# Placing selected image into grid

Tags: ios, image, video, uicollectionview

I'm working on creating an application of which the user will select a photo or video and after the user has selected the photo or video place in into a grid layout. What I'm trying to figure out is how to get the photo or video into the empty grid slot after it is selected.

I'll be using the new collections and what I'm wondering is do I go about a simple check such as if cell is empty than add selection?

Not looking for someone to code for me I do enjoy that just looking for guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into UICollectionView and its classes. Specifically,

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and

```
- (void)reloadData
```